# hierarchy query sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
EmployeeId, Name, ManagerId
1,Mac Manager, null
2,Sue Supervisor, 1
3,Earl Employee, 2
4,Sam Supervisor, 1
5,Ella Employee, 4

Given: Employee Id = 3
```

Can you help me with sql to get the employee plus managers up the chain?

In this example the results would be

```
Earl
Sue
Mac
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [Recursive Queries Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx?ppud=4)

```
declare @EmpID int = 3;

with C as
(
  select E.EmployeeId,
         E.Name,
         E.ManagerId
  from YourTable as E
  where E.EmployeeId = @EmpID
  union all
  select E.EmployeeId,
         E.Name,
         E.ManagerId
  from YourTable as E
    inner join C  
      on E.EmployeeId = C.ManagerId
)
select C.Name
from C
```

[SE-Data](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/82395)

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @current int 
set @current = @empid
while @current is not null begin

   -- do something with it
   print @current

   set @current = (select ManagerId from table where EmployeeId = @current)
end
```